# Find if any member of a group of elements has a class

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to see if any inputs have the class "invalid" with JQuery.

```
$('#formId input').hasClass('invalid');
```

is returning `false`. Even after I've used `.addClass('invalid')` on an input and verified with Chrome's DOM inspector that the class is present.

The below suggestions are not working. My markup is a little bit different than just form>input though.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jv4tG/

Comment: Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Can you show the code you're using (the HTML and the (part of) the script that adds the class? Any chance of a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I'm not seeing the behavior you describe: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/MLHap/

Comment: @KevinBoucher, weird. I may have a bug somewhere else.

Comment: Can I just say that *case matters* (`getNewsLetter` !== `getNewsletter`). [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Jv4tG/1/).

Comment: *sigh.* I hate when I do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the class-name as a selector:

```
$('#formId input.invalid');
```

This will only operate on those elements that have that class, otherwise, as a conditional, you can use `length`:

```
if ($('#formId input.invalid').length) {
    // some elements have that class
}
```

You could also use `filter()`:

```
$('#formId input').filter(function(){
    return $(this).hasClass('invalid');
});
```

Which will limit the selector to only those elements *with* that class, or:

```
$('#formId input').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).hasClass('invalid');
});
```

To return those elements that do *not* have the invalid class-name.

Comment: Just to be sure, if the length == 0, that will equate to false?

Comment: Yeah, `0` is a falsey value, so evaluates to `false`.

Comment: I was about to propose `filter` but... nothing is really better than simple class selector :)

Comment: @ChrisSobolewski Your selector is wrong http://jsfiddle.net/PWLZf/ also http://jsfiddle.net/Hg4KC/

Comment: (@Chris: as also noted in the comment to your question.)